# MonoTouch UIBarButtonItem Icon images in project subfolder

Tags: ios, image, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, uibarbuttonitem

Can anyone explain to me why images for `UIBarButtonItem` only show when I place them into the project root but not when I put them under <projectdir>/images? Build action is "Content" in both cases.

Having my project root cluttered up with image files is not exactly my style.

**UPDATE:** Looks like the issue is that XCode for some reason recognizes the images in the subfolder but when you actually assign them using the dropdownlist to a control, it emits just the filename of the image without the folder into the xib file. So I don't know who is to blame here but I'd say at the moment is not possible to reliably work with images in subfolders in MonoDevelop/MonoTouch.

Comment: I do this all the time - how are you loading the images?

Comment: I've assigned them through XCode 4's Interface Builder.

Comment: hmm.. I always do it in code, using relative path to the app's root.  Have you checked your app bundle after a build to verify it is including the images like you expect?

Comment: Yeah the are included in the root folder.

Comment: I'd suggest putting together a simple test case displaying the problem and submit it as a bug to Xamarin

Answer (score 0):

We actually store all of our images as embedded resources within the application.

In fact, because we have a common library that is used for MonoDroid, MonoTouch, and Windows Phone, the images are all stored in a common library DLL as embedded resources and we can organize the images in any directory/subdirectory configuration that we wish, including images.

This might be something to look at for your scenario.